# Fitting resume content on one page

Tags: spacing, fontsize, cv, resume

So I am new to latex and am pretty lost. Hoping one of you guys could help me out.
So I wrote my resume on latex and its almost 2 pages long. I am really tryna fit it all on one page. 
So I tried reducing the margin size and its really not doing much. 
Are there any other possible ways I could fit it all on one page?

Comment: Maybe an unwanted suggestion but: shortening your contents.

Comment: Other than that: You can reduce margins, font size, line spread, inter word spacing. You can ask TeX to tighten every paragraph by a line (depending on how large your paragraphs are, on short paragraphs this won't do anything).

Comment: However you manage to squeeze it onto a single page make sure that it is easily readable (who would be prepared to read a page in a 6pt font?).

Comment: Use an A3 page?

Comment: Skillmon and Peter Wilson suggested good comments. The thing to keep in mind is that your presentation of your resume is everything. It should be very appealing to the employer. This means that you shouldn't really playing with fonts size nor margins (you have a tiny room to wiggle, but that's about it). You have two pages worth of text, you just can't fit them into one and expect to have a good visual resume.

Comment: At last what you can do depends on the used documentclass and loaded packages. Without seeing any code we can only guess, sorry ...

Comment: alright u guys are so nice. Thank you :)

Comment: @Mensch                                                                      \documentclass{resume} 
\usepackage[left=0.4in,top=0.4in,right=0.4in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} 
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{..5\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]                                                                                              Does this help you get an idea of what I did?

Comment: You can simply not use `geometry` with pretty outdated class `resume.cls`. Try better class `moderncv` with style `banking` ...